# How to run laravel 5.4 websites on a server with PHP version 5.0 to 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.4

I wrote a small content management system using laravel 5.4 version. But the web hosting company uses PHP 5.3 version. When I upload my website, I got errors. Is there any way to run laravel 5.4 applications on servers with the PHP version 5.0  to 5.4? Changing the web hosting company is not a choice.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You can upgrade your PHP on your web host. They may be giving you PHP 5.3 but that does not mean you can not upgrade the php yourself. It can be done on any flavor of linux and windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way around minimum PHP requirements.  You would have to change providers or get your provider to update PHP version (which they should do).

Comment: Is it possible to modify some of the PHP codes in the core laravel framework which are not compatible with the specific PHP version? If it is possible, is there a short way to do it?

Comment: it is possible but there is not practical way of doing it.  if an old version of laravel exists that can run on 5.3, you could always just use the old version of laravel.  that is really the only practical way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Best option in this case is to upgrade your PHP on your Web Host if that is an option.

(1) If your host is running Windows you can find the PHP install info [here](http://windows.php.net/).Also check [here](http://php.net/downloads.php).

(2) If your web host is running Debian GNU based Linux then just run following command:

`apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli`

Comment: Thank you Andy, but I don't have access to upgrade the web hosting company PHP version. I can only make a change on my code.

Comment: OK. One more option is that if they allow you to run docker containers on their host then I will say run the php and laravel using docker container to solve this. You can do a very rudimentary setup using docker-compose and using php-fpm and nginx image ( need two container) and serving the code from your host. You can map your docker container port to which ever port you need on your host to serve it from. But this will need some familiarity with docker.

Comment: Thank you Andy, if there is some kind of steps or instructions to do that, would you share it here please?

Comment: Check with your hosting provider.